Подсчет кол-ва строк в форме


function countLines()



{



  var area = document.getElementById("replace")



        // trim trailing return char if exists



  var text = area.value.replace(/\s+$/g,"")



  var split = text.split("\n")



  return split.length



}



Как сделать, чтобы количество строк отображалось в


<p id="gfg"></p>



в реальном времени?
(без кнопки с alert'ом)

Что значит, в реальном времени? Что за кнопка с алертом из вопроса?

Добавь в [example] разметку формы вместе с этим элементом #replace, чтобы было понятно о чем речь.

я хотел закрепить  рядом с textarea, и чтоб в нем отображался счетчик строк.

У вас скрипт, на сколько можно судить, выводить будет не количество строк, а количество переносов строк. Если в textarea вставить одну длинную строку, которая визуально будет в 10 строк, то ваш скрипт, с большой долей вероятности выведет 1. Тем не менее, без вашей разметки, кнопки и скрипта, откуда выполняется функция, сказать что определенное сложно.



const input = document.getElementById("replace");
const output = document.getElementById("gfg");

function countLines() {
  const textOnly = input.value.replace(/\n+/g, "\n").replace(/\s+$/g, "");
  const split = textOnly.split("\n");
  output.innerText = `${split.length} шт.`;
}

input.addEventListener('input', countLines);
countLines();
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
}
<p id="gfg">0</p>
<textarea id="replace">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Fusce eu tincidunt mi, sit amet laoreet metus.
Nullam ac euismod arcu. Phasellus semper odio ligula.
Donec et sem tincidunt, mollis dui a, vestibulum nisi.


Suspendisse at odio vitae libero pretium vehicula.

Nulla eu lacus ac libero pulvinar mollis.
Donec at metus non leo blandit gravida quis consectetur purus.
</textarea>



